# Jpos alternative in php

Tags: java, php, iso8583, jpos

Hi are there any frameworks or libraries in php equivalent to jpos?

I came across [JAK8583](https://github.com/gdsmith/JAK8583%20JAK8583) php library which can parse and generate **ISO 8583** messages.

However I want a php library which can generate **ISO 8583 response message** for **ISO 8583 request message** .

Please let me know if there are any.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I don't know any alternative but you can always parse the request and set the response fields on that parsed request. 
You can see implementation of ISOMsg.setRespnseMTI as inspiration.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [this](https://github.com/diorahman/iso8583) php library for iso8583.

Please note that in general you cannot throw a request at a library and tell it to give you a response that will be useful.  You need to populate the response with data that is relevant to the transaction.

So normally you would get the request, create a response from the request, populate the response with relevant data, then send it.